# Is Automation possible Using PHP/Curl?

Tags: php, curl, automation

I have a requirement like below.

1. If I visit a website through Curl,
2. and after 30 seconds, I click on any link of that website, will it be considered as a single visit?

I want to get it considered as a single visit. so it can be tracked in analytics or wordpress-jetpack-stats as a single visit.

If this is not possible, Please give me possible solution to do this through PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on how the target server considers "visits". If it's by IP, then there's nothing special you need to do.  If it's by cookie, then you want to make sure you extract the cookie info from the initial request, then send those cookies back with the followup request.

Check out the cookie options in [`curl_setopt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: Ok so, I need to save the cookies from first request's response-header, and send that same cookie in second request's request-header. right?

Comment: Yup, and the curl options do seem to support functionality to track cookies automatically, however, given that your script is running for 30 or more seconds, you may want to store the cookies to disk and you can look into the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` options in `curl_setopt`.